# multiplying valued with different dtypes

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, graph

I am creating a code that allows the user to enter 4 values (a, b, c, and d) for the equation (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d), then the program will output the graph on a window (I am using Tkinter).
however, the code for some reason doesn't work.

To explain a bit my code in the input_check process I am outputting a button on a window with a blank box for the input. when the input is entered the program will check if it is the same as 3 (I will be adding more equations after (therefore it will check which equation the user wants), then it should ask for the values of a, b, c, and d (but it gives an error).

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root.configure(bg='dark blue')


# checking which type of equation the user wants to enter on base of the number inputted
def input_check():
    processing = FALSE
    answer_int = int(answer1.get())
    while processing == FALSE:
        if answer_int == 3:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="You have inputted the number 3")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)
            execution = Button(root, text="execute", command=cubic_equation())
            execution.grid(row=4, column=1)
            processing = TRUE
        else:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="the answer you inputted is invalid, please try again.")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)


label1 = Label(root, text="enter a number: ")
answer1 = Entry(root)
button1 = Button(root, text='enter', command=input_check)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
answer1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

def cubic_equation():
    a = ''
    b = ''
    c = ''
    d = ''

    # converting the Entries from string to float for future calcuations
    def enter_click(event):
        global a
        global b
        global c
        global d
        a = float(a_entry.get())
        b = float(b_entry.get())
        c = float(c_entry.get())
        d = float(d_entry.get())

    a_entry = Entry(root)
    a_entry.grid(row=5, column=0)
    b_entry = Entry(root)
    b_entry.grid(row=6, column=0)
    c_entry = Entry(root)
    c_entry.grid(row=7, column=0)
    d_entry = Entry(root)
    d_entry.grid(row=8, column=0)

    enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter")
    enter_button.grid(row=9, column=0)
    enter_button.bind("<Button-1>", enter_click)
    enter_button.bind("<Return>", enter_click)

    x_axis = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)

    int_x_axis = x_axis.astype(int)
    index = len(int_x_axis) - 1
    last_item = int_x_axis[index]
    global y_base

    

    while last_item < 11:
        y_base = a * x_axis ** 3 + b * x_axis ** 2 + c * x_axis + d

    plt.figure(num=0, dpi=120)
    plt.plot(x_axis, y_base, label="f(x)", linestyle='--')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(linestyle=':')
    plt.xlim([-1000, 1000])
    plt.ylim([-1000, 1000])

    plt.title('graph')
    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')
```

when i run the code this mesage appears:
 `numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('float64')) -> None`

I don't know what this means, and I don't know how to solve this error.
do you know what is the problem? and how do I solve it?

if any other information is required please send me a message, I really need help

Comment: where do you convert the parameters (a, b, c, and d) to dtype float?
I'm missing the logic behind the while loop in the cubic_equation function. would you kindly explain?

Comment: '<U1' means a single character string.  'float64' is a number.  You can't multiply strings and numbers!

Comment: @yannziselman, I didn't convert the parameters to dtype float, (should I do that)?, when I did run the code without the loop an error is produced, and it says that the cubic_eqaution function needs to be put in a loop ( I think because the x_axis is not a single value, but an array of values), I am talking about the loop last_item<11, just to make it clear.
Sorry for replying so late, but I didn’t have internet for a while.

Comment: @hpaulj can I not convert one of them into the same dtype as the other one?